# when Hadoop DataNode is down

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

Regd below statement can anyone clarify below questions ?

Satement:
When a DataNode is down, it does not affect the availability of data or the cluster. NameNode will arrange for replication for the blocks managed by the DataNode that is not available

Questions:

1. When datanode(d1) is down will namenode blindly start replicating blocks(B1,B2..Bn) on other nodes(d2)?
2. But when datanode(d1) is up , what happens to the same existing blocks(B1,B2...Bn) on datanode(d1)?

Explanation:

Lets say datanode d1 has blocks b1 ,b2..Bn Since it is down namenode will start replicating them on to datanode d2 or other. But when d1 is up what happens to the d1 blocks ?

Comment: it becomes over replica and get deleted eventually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DataNodes notice NameNode about receiving or deletion of blocks or they send over list of their replicas periodically. Moreover, NameNode has one still­running thread namely ReplicationMonitor to get under­replication and over­replication under its radar and plans for deletion/replication accordingly

[source](http://www.diva-portal.org/smash/get/diva2:644417/FULLTEXT01.pdf)